# Space in CFBundleDisplayName with plutil

Tags: ios, bash, encoding, cfbundledisplayname

I am trying to rename my CFBundleDisplayName using plutil on my build server. Here is part of the bash script that I am running.

```
BUNDLE_DISPLAY_NAME='MY'"&#x2007;"'APP'
plutil -replace CFBundleDisplayName -string "$BUNDLE_DISPLAY_NAME" $PLIST_ADDRESS
```

I expect this script, changes the CFBundleDisplayName to `"MY&#x2007;APP"` but what I have now is `MY&amp;#x2007;APP`.

Anyone has any idea how can I get my expected output from plutil?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case that anyone faced similar issue with space in CFBundleDisplayName with plutil, what I ended up to do is to copy the `" "` (actual character for [FIGURE SPACE](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2007/index.htm) not the UTF-16 (hex) code) in the script to resolve the problem.

```
BUNDLE_DISPLAY_NAME='MY'" "'APP'
plutil -replace CFBundleDisplayName -string "$BUNDLE_DISPLAY_NAME" $PLIST_ADDRESS
```

Comment: Nice solution, but this space is actually bigger than spaces in other app names on my iOS device. Isn't there a proper way to escape spaces?